# What is the right order to initialize class fields?

Tags: dart

What is the logic here when the programmer initializes `_random` at once but the `_streamController` is initialized in the constructor?

Can all the fields be initialized without a constructor then?

```
RandomStore {
    RandomStore() {
        _streamController = StreamController<int>();

        _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1),
            (_) => _streamController.add(_random.nextInt(100)));

        randomStream = ObservableStream(_streamController.stream);
    }

    late final Timer _timer;

    final _random = Random();

    late final StreamController<int> _streamController;

    late final ObservableStream<int?> randomStream;
    
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can all the fields be initialized without a constructor ?

Yes, you can initialize all fields without having to declare a constructor, but only if you don't need a reference to the current instance (this) or if they are 'late' fields.

The determining factor in choosing where to initialize fields is whether or not you need to have **the reference** (even implicit) **to `this`**.

In Dart `this` is only available from the construcor body; this means in particular that `this` is not usable in the *initializer list* and inside the *inline initializers* (except for the late fields).For terminology, see Glossary below.

`this` is the reference to the current instance, and is required in order to read the instance fields, even if you usually omit it (e.g., in your snippet, `randomStream` is equivalent to `this.randomStream`).

For example, in your snippet, to initialize `randomStream` you need to be able to read the `streamController` field, so you have to mark it with **`late`**; thanks to `late` you can initialize `randomStream` in the constructor body or in the inline initializer (in this second case it will actually be initialized only when you try to access it for the first time; which is an advantage if its initialization is expensive and you want to avoid it as long as possible).

As an alternative to `late`, you could mark the field as **nullable** and initialize it in the constructor body (in which case the field will first be implicitly initialized with a null value; in fact this approach is not usable if the field is `final` and therefore cannot be reassigned).

---

Instead, to initialize the `streamController` field, you don't use a reference to this, so you could avoid the overhead of marking the field with late and you can initialize it in the initializer list or in the inline initializer (it is the same).

Example:

```
class RandomStore {

  final StreamController<int> _streamController;
  
  RandomStore()
   : _streamController = StreamController<int>() {
   
   }
}
```

---

**Is `late` always a good choice?** (UPDATED)

While from the above it might seem that 'late' is a great solution for most situations, the doc suggests avoiding 'late' if it is not really necessary, because:

1. **It is less secure**:
   a late field (also if it has a non-nullable type) entails a risk of errors at runtime similar to that which occurred before the introduction of sound null safety, because Dart does not force you to perform any checks before reading its value (unlike nullable fields, for which access to properties requires the use of not null operator or conditional operator). Note that Dart does not offer the possibility to check if a late field has already been initialized (See Issue `#324` mentioned below)
2. **It adds overhead**:
   under the cover will be created a field with the indicated type, a field -presumably boolean- for keep track of whether the initialization has occurred, and a getter that at each access checks if the initialization had occurred.

Useful sources about late:

- Doc Guide about null safety and late variables https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables
- Dart Best practice about late

  https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-late-when-a-constructor-initializer-list-will-do

  https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-late-variables-if-you-need-to-check-whether-they-are-initialized
- Dart issue #324 [Should we provide a way to query the status of late variables?](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/324)

  a very interesting **insight into 'late'** (the discussion in which the Dart Team decided not to allow the final developers to check if a late field has been initialized)

---

**Note the differences with Java:**

(which personally made it difficult for me to switch from Java to Dart at first)

- `this` in Dart is not available in inline initializers (in Java it is available)
- the `final` fields in Dart must be initialized before the constructor body (in Java they can also be initialized in the constructor body)

**Gloassary:**

```dart
class MyClass {

    MyClass(String v1, String v2) 
      : myField1 = v1, myField2 = v2 //This is the "initializer list"
        //Compared to inline initializers, it allows you to initialize fields using the constructor arguments
    {
        //This is the "constructor body"
        
        myField4 = myField1; //This operation require an implicit reference to `this`; it is equivalent to `myField4 = this.myField1;`
    }       
      
    String myField1;  
    String myField2;    
    
    String myField3 = '3';  //This is the "inline initialization"
    
    late String myField4;


}
```

Comment: good explanation, indeed. so, as for the intital example, there is no need for the _streamController be initialized in the contructor body with late. on the othe side, all the fields could be late and initialized in the constructor. both of the variants would be more logical than the initial example code.

Comment: @rozerro That's right, the initial example isn't consistent in choosing how to initialize fields.
However, while from my answer it seems that **`late`** is a great solution for much cases, in reality I don't see it used very often;  in the Flutter Sdk's sources I have never seen 'late' used if it was avoidable, as in the case of `_streamController`. The doc on Dart Best Practice [Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-late-when-a-constructor-initializer-list-will-do) reports just an equal example as a situation to be avoided. (I will update the answer)